# Do Firebase Security Rules affect user account creation & authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to enable email & password authentication on my Firebase database. However I also want to strictly create accounts and authenticate users on the server rather than on the client. Can I simply set ".read" to false to prevent clients from creating accounts themselves? Or would I need to use custom authentication?

Comment: Creating credentials is simply creating a key/value entry in a hash with an email and bcrypted password. There's no harm here. To "strictly create accounts," just set up security rules to only allow access to users who exist() in a given path. You write the registered users there. The creds hurt nothing and grant nothing without your consent.

Comment: OK. I think I get it. I keep track of users who registered legitimately (through my API). Then I can write my security rules based off of that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict the creation of Email & Password accounts on Firebase. You can only limit what data users can read and write. A user account that has no read/write access to any data is pretty useless.

With custom authentication you could indeed simply not mint a JWT for users that you don't want to create an account for. But as said: this doesn't improve data security, it just means that those user will get "you don't have an account" type message instead of "you don't have access to this data".